# Detect new values when comparing existing variables in a dataframe and add them in a new variable in R

Tags: r

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| First,Second,Other | row,First |
| Second,Other,Other2 | row,Second |

I would like to create a new column with the values that are in col1 and not in col2:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First,Second,Other | row,First | Second,Other |
| Second,Other,Other2 | row,Second | Other,Other2 |

And what if the separator is a `||` instead of a `,`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop rows, split, get the set difference, finally paste them back together again:

```
d$col3 <- apply(d, 1, function(i) {
  paste(setdiff(unlist(strsplit(i[ 1 ], ",")),
                unlist(strsplit(i[ 2 ], ","))), collapse = ",")})

d
#                  col1       col2         col3
# 1  First,Second,Other  row,First Second,Other
# 2 Second,Other,Other2 row,Second Other,Other2
```

If we want to split on `"||"` then apply below changes for *strsplit* in above code:

```
#example for ||
strsplit("First||Second||Other", split = "||", fixed = TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "First"  "Second" "Other"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R approach. If you want `col3` to be a list of vectors, do this

```
sep = ","
d$col3 <- Vectorize(setdiff, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)(
  strsplit(d$col1, sep, fixed = TRUE), 
  strsplit(d$col2, sep, fixed = TRUE)
)
```

Output

```
> d$col3
[[1]]
[1] "Second" "Other" 

[[2]]
[1] "Other"  "Other2"

> d
                 col1       col2          col3
1  First,Second,Other  row,First Second, Other
2 Second,Other,Other2 row,Second Other, Other2
```

If you don't, then do one more step

```
d$col3 <- sapply(d$col3, paste0, collapse = sep)
```

All together

```
sep = ","
d$col3 <- sapply(Vectorize(setdiff, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)(
  strsplit(d$col1, sep, fixed = TRUE), 
  strsplit(d$col2, sep, fixed = TRUE)
), paste0, collapse = sep)
```

Data

```
d <- structure(list(col1 = c("First,Second,Other", "Second,Other,Other2"
), col2 = c("row,First", "row,Second")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```